# Combinar valores según una columna de un dataframe en R

Tags: r

Quería poder combinar los valores que hay en las columnas `Oak`, `Wasteland`, `Edge` y `Crop` de aquellos `Taxa` que son iguales, de un dataframe como este:

```
  View(Datos)

      Taxa                Oak    Wasteland    Edge   Crop
       Allium               0        0         15.9     0
       Allium               0        0           0   10.8
       Cucumis              0        0        15.9     0
       Cucumis              0      12.4          0      0
       Zea_mays             0      12.4          0      0
       Quercus_ilex        6.5       0           0      0
       Quercus_coccifera    0      12.4         0      0


       Taxa                Oak    Wasteland    Edge   Crop
       Allium               0        0         15.9   10.8
       Cucumis              0      12.4        15.9     0
       Zea_mays             0      12.4          0      0
       Quercus_ilex        6.5       0           0      0
       Quercus_coccifera    0      12.4         0      0
```

¿Con qué función podría quitar los duplicados y cómo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varias formas:

```
Datos[!duplicated(Datos)]
```

O usando la función `unique`

```
unique(Datos)
```

O instalando la librería `dplyr`

```
# Instalación 
install.packages("dplyr") 
# Carga
library("dplyr")
# Función 
distinct(Datos)
```

Para agrupar las columnas por operación (sum, max, mean...)

```
aggregate(cbind(Datos$Oak,Datos$Wasteland,Datos$Edge,Datos$Crop), by = list(Datos$Taxa), max)
```

o

```
aggregate(cbind(Oak,Wasteland,Edge,Crop) ~ Taxa, data = Datos, max)
```

o

```
aggregate(Datos[,2:5],by=list(Datos$Taxa), max)
```

o con dplyr

```
require(dplyr)
Datos %>% group_by(Taxa) %>% summarise_each(funs(max))
```

o con data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Datos)
DT[, lapply(.SD, max), by=Taxa]
```

Comment: muchas gracias, aunque no expuse bien mi pregunta, quería combinar aquellas taxas que son iguales uniendo los valores de las columnas de la derecha

Comment: Oh veo, Actualice mi respuesta con varias opciones también espero funcione alguna!

Comment: SIII es eso, he usado esta función que me aportaste previamente:  DatosSSD<-aggregate(cbind(Oak,Wasteland,Edge,Crop) ~ Taxa, data = DatosSD, max)
  Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Según tu ejemplo, en el caso de `Allium` tienes dos registros ligeramente distintos (en realidad no son duplicados), y por el resultado que esperas,  pareciera que necesitas un agrupamiento con  la función `max`.

```
txt <- "Taxa   Oak    Wasteland    Edge   Crop
Allium               0        0         15.9     0
Allium               0        0         15.9   10.8
Cucumis              0      12.4        15.9     0
Cucumis              0      12.4          0      0
Zea_mays             0      12.4          0      0
Quercus_ilex        6.5       0           0      0
Quercus_ilex        6.5       0           0      0
Quercus_coccifera   6.5      12.4         0      0"

aggregate(cbind(Oak,Wasteland,Edge,Crop) ~ Taxa, df, max)
```

La salida:

```
               Taxa Oak Wasteland Edge Crop
1            Allium 0.0       0.0 15.9 10.8
2           Cucumis 0.0      12.4 15.9  0.0
3 Quercus_coccifera 6.5      12.4  0.0  0.0
4      Quercus_ilex 6.5       0.0  0.0  0.0
5          Zea_mays 0.0      12.4  0.0  0.0
```

- Con `aggregate()` hacemos el agrupamiento usando la sintaxis `aggregate(formula, data, funcion)`
- Con `cbind` creamos las columnas agrupadas para cada `Taxa`

Comment: Tienes razón, he cometido una errata al poner el ejemplo (ya lo he corregido). Aún así me salta este error "Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :   'data' argument is of the wrong type" ¿A qué puede deberse? Un saludo y gracias de antemano

Comment: @AdriánP.L. : Verifica que `data` sea efectivamente un `data.frame` clásico, la función `aggregate`requiere que lo sea, sino intenta castearlo antes mediante `as.data.frame(data)`